# JavaScript array of objects sort by specific property and then group by custom priority values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, grouping, lodash

I have array of objects and my requirement was to group users by status (online users should come first) while sort grouped users by name.
I am able to achieve result but here I am using lodash **concat** function separately. Can anyone help to use it along with **chain** function?

**Code:**

```
  import _ from 'lodash';

  const { online = [], offline = [] } = _.chain(users)
    .sortBy([(e) => _.toLower(e.name)])
    .groupBy((e) => e.status)
    .value();
  const result = _.concat(online, offline);
  console.log('grouped users sorted by name => ', result);
```

**Input:**

```
let users = [
    {
        'name': 'C',
        'status': 'online'
    },
    {
        'name': 'd',
        'status': 'online'
    },
    {
        'name': 'a',
        'status': 'offline'
    },
    {
        'name': 'b',
        'status': 'online'
    },
    {
        'name': 'f',
        'status': 'offline'
    },
    {
        'name': 'e',
        'status': 'offline'
    }
];
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        'name': 'b',
        'status': 'online'
    },
    {
        'name': 'C',
        'status': 'online'
    },
    {
        'name': 'd',
        'status': 'online'
    },
    {
        'name': 'a',
        'status': 'offline'
    },
    {
        'name': 'e',
        'status': 'offline'
    },
    {
        'name': 'f',
        'status': 'offline'
    }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily without lodash too.

You can use a customized sort function when calling the `sort()` function of an array. Create a sort string including a 0 for online users and a 1 for offline users followed by the name. Then use this sort string in the comparison.

```js
let users = [{
    'name': 'C',
    'status': 'online'
  },
  {
    'name': 'd',
    'status': 'online'
  },
  {
    'name': 'a',
    'status': 'offline'
  },
  {
    'name': 'b',
    'status': 'online'
  },
  {
    'name': 'f',
    'status': 'offline'
  },
  {
    'name': 'e',
    'status': 'offline'
  }
];

users.sort((a, b) => {
  let sortStringA = (a.status.toUpperCase() == 'ONLINE' ? 0 : 1) + a.name.toUpperCase();
  let sortStringB = (b.status.toUpperCase() == 'ONLINE' ? 0 : 1) + b.name.toUpperCase();
  if (sortStringA < sortStringB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (sortStringA > sortStringB) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});

console.log(users);
```

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaijens simple and straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce`,`filter` & `sort`. Create a separate array and add the status in order you want the final array to be be. Then inside the reduce callback use `filter` to get the elements of that status and use `sort` to sort the elements in order of `name`

```js
let sortStatus = ['online', 'offline'];
let users = [{
    name: 'C',
    status: 'online'
  },
  {
    name: 'd',
    status: 'online'
  },
  {
    name: 'a',
    status: 'offline'
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    status: 'online'
  }
];
let data = sortStatus.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.push(
    ...users
    .filter(item => item.status === curr)
    .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
  );
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks @brk I was looking for solution using lodash or with plain js (but simple solution)

Answer (score 1):

If You can correct input:

```js
let users = [
    {
        name: 'C',
        status: 'online'
    },
    {
        name: 'd',
        status: 'online'
    },
    {
       name: 'a',
        status: 'offline'
    },
    {
        name: 'b',
        status: 'online'
    },
    {
        name: 'f',
        status: 'offline'
    },
    {
        name: 'e',
        status: 'offline'
    }
];

const sorted = users.sort((a, b) => {
if (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) {
    return a.status.toLowerCase() < b.status.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
  }
   return b.status.toLowerCase() < a.status.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1;;

})
console.log(sorted )
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikola Pavicevic